# React Babel can't parse Arrow functions, shows directory instead of app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am so confused on why this does not work. I added babel-loader and all the plugins. 
But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| const App = () => {
>   return <div> <h1>Hi!</h1></div>;
| };
| 
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

my packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  return <div> <h1>Hi!</h1></div>;
};


render(< App />, document.getDocumentById('root'));
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions", "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Try putting options in the `use` object under an `options` key for the babel loader. Maybe it isn't pulling from your .babelrc

Comment: Check out this issue: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173

Comment: May I ask you to put the screenshot of your project path and root files into your post? I guess something.

Comment: @AmerllicA what do you want a screenshot of exactly? My IDE window? Or my terminal with `ls -al` ?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St, Forget about the screenshot, I just wanna know your `.babelrc` or `.Babelrc` naming. take it easy. I leave an answer.

Comment: changed to what I actually named them in my code

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, the bundler cannot see your presets, so you can put the presets in the Webpack configuration file, like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { // ↓↓↓ here is the preset configs
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Or you can add it inside the `package.json` file, exactly like below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
```

I hope this post helps you. If the first part isn't correct please tell me to omit it.

Comment: actually in my code files the name is `.babelrc`, I just wrote it there for easier reading. I'll edit that. I'll try loading presets in the way you mentioned here tho.

Comment: I have actually already tried this. Did not work. However, I did add presets to my `package.json` I didn't realize you can do that. Makes for an easier set up!

Comment: @KyleCalica-St, maybe you should install `babel-preset-react-app` in your project and add its name inside your `babel-loader` presets configs just like CRA configs.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St, If the `babel-preset-react-app` helps you, please tell me to edit my answer.

Comment: did not help. I actually moved out all the code above and saw I had an exrta `}` making my `webpack.config.js` invalid. It works now.